# I'm trying to build up options from an array data value using jsView

Tags: arrays, html-select, jsviews

if you have an array of items, without properties, how do you access the value inside a for loop?
I currently get the right number of options, but I haven't found the correct syntax to get the value of the option.

there's a working jsfiddle at: http://jsfiddle.net/geewhizbang/Y44Gm/4/

```
var data = {
    items: [{
        "title": "First Drop Down",
            "hist": "Secondary",
            "dec": "Priority",
            "options": ["Priority", "Secondary"],
            "type": "select"
    }, {
        "title": "Second Drop Down",
            "hist": "Competitive Widget",
            "dec": "Competitive Widget",
            "options": ["Yadda", "Badda", "Bing", "Mobile", "Server", "Client", "Snickerdoodle"],
            "type": "select"
    }]
};
$.views.converters("dateFormat", function (val) {
   if (val == null) return "";
    var d = new Date(val);
    if (d.getFullYear() == "1900") return "";
    return d.getMonth() + "/" + d.getDate() + "/" + d.getFullYear();
});
$template = $.templates("#template");
$("#container").html($template.render(data));
```

the body of this, including template:

```
<div id="container">
    <script id="template" type="text/x-jsrender">
    {{for items}}
        <div class="bodyItem">
            <div class="colDec">
                <p>{{>title}}</p>
                {{if type == "select"}}
                    <select data-link="{{>dec}}">
                        {^{for options}}
                            <option value="{{#}}">{#}</option>
                        {{/for}}
                    </select>
                {{else}}
                    {{if type == "date"}}
                        <input value="{{dateFormat:dec}}" class="date" />
                    {{else}}
                        <div contentEditable="true">{{>dec}}</div>
                    {{/if}}
                {{/if}}
            </div>
            <div class="colHist">
                <p>{{>title}}</p>
                {{if type == "date"}}
                    <input value="{{dateFormat:dec}}" class="date" />
                {{else}}
                    <div>{{>dec}}</div>
                {{/if}}
            </div>
        </div>
    {{/for}}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If options is an array of strings, you need:

```
<select data-link="dec">
    {^{for options}}
        <option value="{{:#data}}">{{:#data}}</option>
    {{/for}}
</select>
```

Note also the data-link expression on the select element.

In general, in your jsfiddle, you can use data-linking much more. For example:

```
<div>{^{>dec}}</div>
```

(Note the ^)

And to do data-linking you need

```
$template.link("#container", data);
```

rather than just calling render...

There are more changes needed, but here is an update of your jsfiddle which does select binding: http://jsfiddle.net/BorisMoore/Y44Gm/5/